# Can I see how long someone has had a file locked in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was wondering if it was possible to see when someone locked a file in Subversion (using TortoiseSVN if that is important?)? I know how to view who has it locked but was unsure if it were possible to see for how long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The repository browser shows the lock information in the last column.
- The "check for modifications" dialog shows the lock information as well after you click on the `check repository` button

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, `svn info URL` will give you when a lock was created on the file (if one exists).